# Headless selenium multiBrowser?

Tags: python, selenium, web

I am building a website and would like to fetch data from other websites by scrapping them. So what I will do is scrape data using selenium and Beautiful soup and add it to a database and update it every lets say 24 hrs. But how is it possible to run selenium in the backend of a website because I need  to download a specified web driver locally.

Comment: depends on the server that you use, but you could probably download the selenium webdriver onto your server and use it with your script. Some servers already have it installed (like pythonanywhere)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is helpful for the community if you provide some more details of the attempts you've made so far. Please review the guidelines here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask